# Chrome console: show function properties

Tags: google-chrome, console, google-chrome-devtools

I want to see function in console as object. For example if I write

```
Object
```

it shows me

```
function Object() { [native code] }
```

but I want something like

```
{bind: function(){...}, call: function(){...}, hasOwnProperty: function(){...}, ...}
```

How can I do this in chrome console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
console.dir(Object)
```

shows

```
▶ function Object() { [native code] }
```

which can be expanded

```
arguments: null
caller: null
create: function create() { [native code] }
```

Answer (score 1):

IT is not clear why you need this but there is a workaround. You can just write dot at the end and see the complete list of suggestions. For the text window.getElementById. devtools shows the list with apply, arguments, bind, call, caller, constructor, hasOwnProperty etc.